# Silver spaces in JavaFX layout

Tags: java, javafx

I created Java application layout, but I'm not entirely happy with it because there are silver spaces in it that I can't get rid of. How can I fix it. I attach the screen of the window and its code below.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3pjl.png): [screen of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3pjl.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane id="root" prefHeight="750" prefWidth="1250" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="cc13app.MainFrameController">
    <children>
        <VBox id="root_vbox" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="750" prefWidth="1250">
            <children>
                <Label styleClass="title" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="1250" text="CC13 DESKTOP APPLICATION" />
                <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1250.0">
                    <items>
                        <VBox id="left_side" maxWidth="350" minWidth="350" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="350.0" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                            <children >
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="Control Type" />
                                <ChoiceBox fx:id="control_type_choice_box" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="chc_box" />
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="Observed Value" />
                                <ChoiceBox fx:id="observed_value_choice_box" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="chc_box" />
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="K_P Constant" />
                                <TextField fx:id="kp_input" styleClass="txt_field"/>
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="K_I Constant" />
                                <TextField fx:id="ki_input" styleClass="txt_field"/>
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="K_D Constant" />
                                <TextField fx:id="kd_input" styleClass="txt_field"/>
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="Max Error Sum Constant" />
                                <TextField fx:id="max_error_input" styleClass="txt_field"/>
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Label styleClass="lbl" text="Divisor Constant" />
                                <TextField fx:id="divisor_input" styleClass="txt_field"/>
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="25.0" />
                                <Button fx:id="send_config_button" styleClass="btn" text="SEND CONFIG" />
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />
                                <Button fx:id="start_stop_data_sending_button" styleClass="btn" text="START DATA RECEIVING" />
                                <Separator orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="15.0" />

                            </children></VBox>
                        <SplitPane fx:id="right_side" maxWidth="900" minWidth="900" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="900.0">
                            <LineChart fx:id="line_chart">
                                <xAxis>
                                    <NumberAxis fx:id="category_axis" side="BOTTOM" />
                                </xAxis>
                                <yAxis>
                                    <NumberAxis fx:id="number_axis" side="LEFT" />
                                </yAxis>
                            </LineChart>
                        </SplitPane>
                    </items></SplitPane>
            </children></VBox>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry for being so imprecise, I'm new in it. I have attached a new photo where I have marked in green the place I have in mind .

Comment: looking at your image... the circled bits are there because you put them there.
The thicker vertical bar is the separator in the SplitPane. Are you saying you want to hide the SplitPane seperator bar?

Comment: oh yeah, that's what I meant. Now knowing the name I know how to fix it. Thanks